# How to read this decompiled statement?

Tags: c++, assembly, decompiler

When I decompiled a function I got the following code

```
((void(__thiscall**)(int))(*v4 + 4))(v4);
```

*v4 in this context is a virtual table. I can't really break it down (who is resolved first and the exact meaning of it).

I'd kindly ask you to help me resolving this step by step so I can understand how this works.

Comment: Looks like v4 is probably the "this" pointer, it dereferences that to get the vtable, indexes into that to get the method, casts the result of that to a function call, then passes "this" to that function (which will be a member function).

Comment: `When I threw this into Visual Studio I was surprised that it got accepted` - what do you mean by that? That statement won't compile by itself.  Maybe you can show the code where you copied it into a VS project.

Comment: The `*`'s after `__thiscall` look like a syntax error to me.

Comment: Given the `+4`, and assuming a 32-bit program, it's probably the second declared virtual method in the class that's getting invoked.

Comment: @selbie you are right I've edited that part out for now
also thank you everyone I now understand it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
(
    (   // these parens around the type declaration are a cast
        void (__thiscall**)(int) // this type declaration:
                                 // a pointer to pointer to function taking int parameter
    )
    (*v4 + 4) // this is a pointer expression
              // this pointer is being cast to a function
) // this is a function pointer
( // these paren's invoke the function
    v4     // this is the parameter being passed to the function 
);
```

The only thing that is strange is that `v4`, passed as parameter, is not an int as the cast says — it is a pointer.

It looks like `v4` is an object, and the vtable is the first member of the object, so `*v4` refers to the vtable.  `*v4+4` refers to the 5th vtable entry.

Comment: The other weird thing is that calling a function through a double pointer actually *doesn't* compile on any of GCC, Clang, or MSVC. Something extremely fishy is going on here. Perhaps the decompilation software just fails to output certain dereferences...

Answer (score 2):

```
((void(__thiscall**)(int))(*v4 + 4))(v4);
                            ^^ pointer
                           ^^^ dereference it
                           ^^^^^^^ add 4
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ cast to void (__thiscall**)(int)
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ Call with v4 as the parameter
```

`void (__thiscall**)(int)` is a pointer to a pointer to a function, which has an `int` parameter.

Presumably:

- `v4` is the address of an object.
- `*v4` reads the vtable pointer from the object.
- `*v4 + 4` is the slot in the vtable where the function pointer we want to call is.  It's a pointer to that function pointer.
- The first parameter is `this`

Note that we're calling a pointer to a function pointer. Function pointers are automatically dereferenced in C(++), but I wasn't aware that that also applied to pointers to function pointers. Evidently, it does.

Answer (score 0):

This statement use some weird calling convention specification from Microsoft, but what it basically is, is just a cast, followed by a call.

`(void(**)(int))` this type is a pointer to a pointer to a function taking int as parameter, and returning void.

`__thiscall` is a calling convention specifier only supported by Microsoft compiler as you can see [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/thiscall?view=vs-2019)

`(*v4 + 4)` This part is just dereferencing v4, then adding 4, so I'd guess that *v4 is a pointer, and the type of v4 is something like `void **`

Wrapping all up, this statement de-reference v4, add 4 to this value, cast this new pointer as a pointer to a pointer to function, then invoke this by passing v4.

As pointed out by others, it's weird that v4 is passed as an int. However, as the architecture seems to be x86, this should not break anything, as int and pointer should have the same size of 32bits.